# string with "$" not giving expected output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string `"$$$$$1.00"`
Need to replace all '$' with empty string. I don't know the exact number of '$' as I fetch it from server.

I tried using

```
"$$$$$1.00".replace(/$/g, "")
```

which is not working out.

I know I can run through the loop and remove it. Is there any way to do that.
Also, why it is not working ?

It is working in this [case](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace2)

I have added the JSfiddle link for the simple executable
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Uthistran/cw6gzu45/3/)

Comment: `$` is *a special character in regular expressions*. You have to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign (`$`) in the RegExp as this means the end of the string in RegExp world.

Refactor to:

```js
"$$$$$1.00".replace(/\$/g, "")
```

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj, accidentally wrote 'replace' instead of 'escape' for some reason; noticed as soon as I posted and had to do a quick ninja edit is the likely reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace them all, you should use `/\$+/`to match 1 or more of them and make sure you escape the `$` with `\$` to match the literal string "$"

```
"$$$$$1.00".replace(/\$+/, "")
```

Comment: or else use the global flag as suggested below

Comment: i will go with the other one as I missed only the escaping part